# Regex pattern for localization

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex pattern to fix a localize issue.

The usual delimiters are "." "," or "_" which i have stored into an array of delimiters.

I'm trying to find a pattern with match any of these delimiters which also ends with one or more 0.

For example 3,000 or 3,0 3.0 3.00

Comment: Regex would not be my first choice for addressing localization of number format. What system and language are you using? You should check to see what localization functions are available.

Comment: `(.+?\.0{1,}$)|(.+?_0{1,}$)` This should match any item which ends in period with 1 or more zeroes or an item which ends with _ with 1 or more zeroes.

Comment: Can you provide example inputs and outputs of what you're trying to accomplish? Regexps can be very sensitive to the context of the input.

Comment: @DaichiJameson I'm mostly interested if it's finding values that match the pattern.  For example: 3,0 should match, 3,01 should not match , 3,000 should match

Answer (score 0):

## You could try positive lookahead

If indeed your data always has *one or more 0* after any delimiter, using a *positive lookahead* ( `(?=0+)` in this case) might be what you are looking for...

More precisely, for the numbers you gave:

```
s/([_.,](?=0+))/g
```

should do the trick!

You could try it out and experiment with regex [here](https://regexr.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

We could likely start with an expression similar to:

```
\d+[.,](\d+)?[0]
```

and add additional boundaries to it, if we like so.

For instance, if we wish to capture the delimiters, we would be adding a capturing group:

```
\d+([.,])(\d+)?[0]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dnAEmx/1/)

Or if we wish to remove delimiters, we would expand it to:

```
(\d+)([.,])(\d+)?([0])
```

and replace it with:

```
$1$3$4
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BgUAf/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(\d+)([.,])(\d+)?([0])/gm;
const str = `3,000
3,0
3.0
3.00`;
const subst = `$1$3$4`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works for most cases, but it's a false positive for 3,01 for example, which does not end in 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use add the delimiters in a character class `[_.,]` and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the number being part of a larger word.

If thet are the only value, you might also use anchors to assert the start `^` and the ends `$` of the string.

```
\b\d+[_.,]\d*0\b
```

That will match:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `[_.,]` Match any of the listed in the character class
- `\d*0` Match 0+ digits followed by a zero
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3Sobn/1)